# Run multiple instances of JBOSS EAP 7

Tags: java, spring, jboss, jboss7.x

Lately I am dealing with creating different profiles of Jboss EAP 7. I want to manage to run under the same default instance (127.0.0.1) different ports or servers, I don't know how to say it correctly. In a previous job I handled this form, we had 3 different profiles of jboss, and always using the same URL only changed the port depending on the type of deploy. Also we have 03 different ways to access to the console management. Port of applications, port of domain, and port of administration. We also had the same paths to check the deployments folder and logs there was only a difference in the folder with the profile name.  I want to achieve this in my current job, since I proposed it.  I've searched how to do it, but the information is very poor, Searching in web and YouTube.  What have I done?  I modified the standalone.xml, created different socket binding, created another server, created another interface and then I only managed to get up to 2 different ports under the same URL.  In one I managed to deploy, and in another I did not.  Besides, I still don't know how to create a folder of logs and deploys for each profile. I need to deploy different wars, in different profiles. For example profile Data port 8081 only for wars of web services. Port 8082 only for wars of front-end.

Thanks in advance. Lot of hugs

Comment: Did you take a look at domain mode ? You could create a configuration for each 'profile' and have a single point of control.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I guess you are doing the right thing. The simplest approach is to add a **port offset** in the socket-binding-group in the standalone.xml. E.g.:

`<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="100">`

Which would shift all ports by 100. So 8080 will be 8180.